# Getting values of Grid's individual nodes (JAVA)

Tags: java, grid

I want to create a program that can simulate the influence of a social structure of a matrix / grid.  It's like an Erdos Renyi structure, but an nxn matrix where each node initially has a random value of +1 or -1.  Each node has 4 neighbors (top, bottom, left, right) which also has values of +1 or -1.  Thus, I can find the neighborhood of each node, which should be just a list / vector of the 4 values of those neighbors.  The value of each node is then influenced by the neighbors' values, and the grid's values keep simulating and changing until an equilibrium is reached.

So far, I have a code which can create a grid with random -1 or +1 variables.  Now, I am not sure how to get the values of each node (and its neighbors) inside the main method.  I am a little confused as to how to go about this project so far, as in how to get the values.

In the main method, I cannot do like... int x = grid[0][1] etc.  Sorry that I'm rusty in Java, but what topics can I look up in finding out the procedure to do this?  I can't remember what it's called.

Also, is there a way that I can edit what each button (or node) on the grid says in the main method?  Like, I can change it while it's looping, and I can also write what the values of its neighbors are?  Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class Grid {
JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // create frame
static JButton[][] grid; 
// constructor
public Grid (int w, int l) {
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(w, l));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    // create grid
    grid = new JButton[w][l]; 

    for (int y = 0; y < l; y++) {
        int value = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            // probability p
            double p = 0.5;
            // randomly allocate opinion
            double random = Math.random();
            if (random <= p)
                value = -1;
            else if (random > p)
                value = 1;
            grid[x][y] = new JButton("" + value);
            frame.add(grid[x][y]);
        }
    }
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
    // DIMENSION
    // int d = 2; 
    // LENGTH
    int l = 2;
    // WIDTH
    int w = 2;
    new Grid(l,w); // create new Grid with parameters

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your approach a little bit, so it is more object-oriented. I hope this example makes clear, what you have to do. To get an basic understanding, google keywords like "encapsulation" or "object-orientation". There are many tutorials out there.

```
public class Grid {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JButton[][] grid; // Has to be a field of the object. static would make it to an field of the class

    public Grid (int w, int l) {
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(w, l));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        createGrid (w, l);
    }

    private void createGrid (int w, int l) {
        // Your above implementation
    }

    public void stepInSimulation () {
        // Your algorithm, you want to implement
    }

    public JButton[][] getGrid () {
        return grid;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Grid grid = new Grid(2,2);
        grid.getGrid ()[0][1]; // Access a value
        grid.stepInSimulation (); // Do a step, call it in while loop, to do multiple steps
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.